# jQuery Socialist setup issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-socialist

I recently downloaded jQuery Socialist. For some reason I cannot get it working and confused as to why? Is there more to the setup I am missing here?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='../jquery.socialist.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').socialist({
        networks: [
            {name:'facebook',id:'linkhere'},
            {name:'pinterest',id:'linkhere'},
            {name:'twitter',id:'linkhere'}
           ],
        isotope:false,
        random:false,
        fields:['source','heading','text','date','image','followers','likes']
    });
});
</script>
```

I just get a loading symbol?

relevant HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Any errors or 404 in your js console?

Comment: what is the error in your console?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  zero errors. I am loading it locally on MAMP, would this be causing an issue?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V3V3w/ Fiddle

Comment: @BjoernRennhak just not working firefox and does not layout properly in chrome. No idea the issue.

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML you have for this piece of code?

Comment: @BjoernRennhak edit above post. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong, as far as I am concerned it is a straight forward and easy plugin? even the downloaded example from github did not work for me?

Comment: If you just get a loading symbol then the ID you use is incorrect in the relevant media entries.

Answer (score 2):

See here - http://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/23U4J/

its running well and working. If you are getting only loading symbol that means plugin is working fine and plugin is unable to load your data. Did you forget to change -

```
id:'linkhere'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for not loading is not because of incorrect id, its because you have included facebook, twitter, linkedin etc. for each one of it we should have a api key and should be registered there first then only it will be accessible.

only the rss feed will run fine because we have to give the total url of the feed.

So please get ur ids from the sites below

Linked in : marketing.linkedin.com/company-pages

Youtube : gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html#Response

FeedsBurner (whole url need to be placed to reach your feed): feeds.feedburner.com/good/lbvp

Facebook : graph.facebook.com/ or developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

When you run the example above remove all of the media except twitter (with a valid id) and then reload. You will notice that it loads correctly. After that add one by one the media entries and see if it still loads. One media entry causes the entire plugin to fail. I suspect you used an incorrect ID or we have a bug here.

I tried this locally and it runs fine.

Comment: I am still having no luck. The example page found in the file downloaded from github with the example media feeds from will not even show a load symbol or show up now. Ready to give up on it. Lost for words...